# tikz 3-d object

Tags: tikz-3dplot

Can the next code be drawn as a 3-d object

```
{
\begin{minipage}[c]{.7\textwidth}
\vskip -15.cm
{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [thin,orange,fill=yellow]
(.25,.25) --  (.25,0) --  (.5,0) --  (.5,.25) --  (.75,.25) --  (.75,.5) --  (.5,.5) --  (.5,.75) --  (.25,.75) --  (.25,.5) --  (0,.5) -- 

 (0,.25) -- cycle ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\vskip -.7cm
\hskip -.06cm
{{\textcolor{red}{{\huge{\textbf{{Na}}}}}}}
}
\end{minipage}
}
```

Comment: An empty page? Sure, shouldn't be a problem. I completed your code in the most obvious way, fixed the compilation error, compiled and get an empty page (except for the page number). So, yes, I guess that can be created in 3D since nothing is possible in even more dimensions, if necessary.

Comment: Changing the code a bit, I managed to produce a very small yellow plus symbol with a larger red 'Na' written over it. What are you asking exactly? And what does this have to do with `tikz-3dplot`? By the way, `\huge` is a switch. It doesn't take an argument.

Comment: Can the next code also be drawn as a 3-d object. I tried but I failed because I have limited knowledge how to do it. Thank you in advance. I appreciate very much your answer.

    {
    \begin{minipage}[c]{.7\textwidth}
    {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [thin,green,fill=yellow]
    (0,.25) -- (.75,.25) -- (.75,.5)  -- (0,.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \vskip -.38cm
    \hskip -.38cm
{{\textcolor{brown}{{\Large{\textbf{{HCO$_{3}$}}}}}}}
    }
    \end{minipage}
    }

Comment: @cfr Thank you very much. Can the next code also be drawn as a 3-d object. I tried but I failed because I have limited knowledge how to do it. Thank you in advance. I appreciate very much your answer. { \begin{minipage}[c]{.7\textwidth} { \begin{tikzpicture} \draw [thin,green,fill=yellow] (0,.25) -- (.75,.25) -- (.75,.5) -- (0,.5); \end{tikzpicture} \vskip -.38cm \hskip -.38cm {{\textcolor{brown}{{\Large{\textbf{{HCO$_{3}$}}}}}}} } \end{minipage} }

Comment: I think you should ask a new question. You can link to this one for background. (The site works best with one question per question. It makes it easier for people to find existing questions/answers and keeps it clear which question answers are addressing.) You might say which of the solutions I posted you are using when asking the new question. I wasn't quite sure what you had in mind - hence the variations. But clarifying that would help with answering the new question. If you post a comment with a link here, I can take a look at your new question if nobody else answers it first.

Comment: My solutions are not really 3D, of course, I'm just faking it one way or another. (But often this is more than enough, of course. Inability to rotate the object isn't a problem unless you want to rotate it!)

Comment: @cfr Hello cfr. I want to use your answer, which is very helpful to me, to draw the next object, which is related to the first one, but with different orientation (using minus sign instead of plus)
 { \begin{minipage}[c]{.7\textwidth} { \begin{tikzpicture} \draw [thin,green,fill=yellow] (0,.25) -- (.75,.25) -- (.75,.5) -- (0,.5); \end{tikzpicture} \vskip -.38cm \hskip -.38cm {{\textcolor{brown}{{\Large{\textbf{{HCO$_{3}$}}}}}}} } \end{minipage} }

Comment: As I say, please ask a new question and please make clear *which* of my solutions you are trying to use. Your code doesn't make that at all clear as it does not seem to show your attempt to adapt any of the solutions I posted. A new question can be related to a previous one and, if it is, it should link to the previous one.

Comment: I would like to make the following drawing
    \begin{minipage}[c]{.7\textwidth}
    {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [thin,green,fill=yellow]
    (0,.25) -- (.75,.25) -- (.75,.5)  -- (0,.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \vskip -.38cm
    \hskip -.38cm
{{\textcolor{brown}{{\Large{\textbf{{HCO$_{3}$}}}}}}}
    }
    \end{minipage}

using your third method

Comment: And? But not here. If you have a new question, ask a new question. Link here if appropriate. It isn't clear what the problem is. You seem to have code of some kind. That is, you can change the molecular formula in that way, yes. If you have problems, ask a new question which makes clear what you've got and what you are having trouble with. Just repeating it over and over in comments is really not doing much. We are just going in circles.

Comment: @cfr I posted my question in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295062/drawing-a-tikz-3-d-object

The reason I asked the question as a comment is that when I ask it as a separate post, I get a reply saying that I should have posted it as a comment in my original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

[image: Na+]

Or this?

[image: More Na+]

Or this?

[image: Further Na+]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\newlength\cw
\setlength\cw{2.5mm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [thin, orange, fill=yellow]
    (-.5\cw,.5\cw) |- ++(\cw,\cw) coordinate [midway] (a) coordinate (b) |- ++(\cw,-\cw) coordinate [midway] (c) coordinate (d) |- ++(-\cw,-\cw) coordinate [midway] (e) coordinate (f) |- ++(-\cw,-\cw) coordinate [midway] (g) coordinate (h) |- ++(-\cw,\cw) coordinate [midway] (i) coordinate (j) |- coordinate [midway] (k)  cyclecoordinate (l);
    \foreach \i in {a,b,...,l}
    {
      \coordinate (\i 1) at ([xshift=.25\cw,yshift=.25\cw]\i);
%     \node [font=\tiny] at (\i 1) {\i};
    }
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
      \path [fill=yellow] (a) -- (a1) -- (b1) -- (c1) -- (d1) -- (e1) -- (e) |- (c) |- cycle (k) -- (k1) -- (a |- k1) |- cycle (g) -- (g1) |-  (f) -- cycle;
      \foreach \i in {a,b,c,d,e,k,g} \draw [thin, orange] (\i) -- (\i 1);
      \draw [thin, orange] (a1) -| (c1) -| (e1) (k1) -- (k1 -| a) (g1) -- (g1 |- f);
    \end{scope}
  \node [text=red, font=\huge\bfseries, anchor=center, yshift=.5\cw, xshift=.125\cw] at (0,0) {Na};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [thin, orange, fill=yellow]
    (-.5\cw,.5\cw) |- ++(\cw,\cw) coordinate [midway] (a) coordinate (b) |- ++(\cw,-\cw) coordinate [midway] (c) coordinate (d) |- ++(-\cw,-\cw) coordinate [midway] (e) coordinate (f) |- ++(-\cw,-\cw) coordinate [midway] (g) coordinate (h) |- ++(-\cw,\cw) coordinate [midway] (i) coordinate (j) |- coordinate [midway] (k)  cyclecoordinate (l);
    \foreach \i in {a,b,...,l}
    {
      \coordinate (\i 1) at ([xshift=.25\cw,yshift=.25\cw]\i);
%     \node [font=\tiny] at (\i 1) {\i};
    }
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
      \path [fill=yellow] (a) -- (a1) -- (b1) -- (c1) -- (d1) -- (e1) -- (e) |- (c) |- cycle (k) -- (k1) -- (a |- k1) |- cycle (g) -- (g1) |-  (f) -- cycle;
      \foreach \i in {a,b,c,d,e,k,g} \draw [thin, orange] (\i) -- (\i 1);
      \draw [thin, orange] (a1) -| (c1) -| (e1) (k1) -- (k1 -| a) (g1) -- (g1 |- f);
    \end{scope}
    \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using 100-100*\i] in {.25,.245,...,0}
    \node [text=red!\j!black, font=\huge\bfseries, anchor=center, yshift=.475\cw+\i\cw, xshift=-.125\cw+\i\cw] at (0,0) {Na};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using 50-200*\i] in {.25,.245,...,0}
  \filldraw [yellow!\j!orange]
    (-.5\cw+\i\cw,.5\cw+\i\cw) |- ++(\cw,\cw)  |- ++(\cw,-\cw) |- ++(-\cw,-\cw) |- ++(-\cw,-\cw) |- ++(-\cw,\cw) |-  cycle;
  \draw [thin, draw=yellow!50!orange, fill=yellow]
    (-.5\cw,.5\cw) |- ++(\cw,\cw) coordinate [midway] (a) coordinate (b) |- ++(\cw,-\cw) coordinate [midway] (c) coordinate (d) |- ++(-\cw,-\cw) coordinate [midway] (e) coordinate (f) |- ++(-\cw,-\cw) coordinate [midway] (g) coordinate (h) |- ++(-\cw,\cw) coordinate [midway] (i) coordinate (j) |- coordinate [midway] (k)  cycle coordinate (l);
    \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using 100-100*\i] in {.25,.245,...,0}
    \node [text=red!\j!black, font=\huge\bfseries, anchor=center, yshift=.475\cw+\i\cw, xshift=-.125\cw+\i\cw] at (0,0) {Na};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I rather liked the way the letters came out. I didn't think it would work at all.

Comment: Hello cfr. I want to use your answer, which is very helpful to me, to draw the next object, which is related to the first one, but with different orientation (using minus sign instead of plus)
 { \begin{minipage}[c]{.7\textwidth} { \begin{tikzpicture} \draw [thin,green,fill=yellow] (0,.25) -- (.75,.25) -- (.75,.5) -- (0,.5); \end{tikzpicture} \vskip -.38cm \hskip -.38cm {{\textcolor{brown}{{\Large{\textbf{{HCO$_{3}$}}}}}}} } \end{minipage} }

Comment: Hello cfr. I want to use your answer, which is very helpful to me, to draw the next object, which is related to the first one, but with different orientation (using minus sign instead of plus) { \begin{minipage}[c]{.7\textwidth} { \begin{tikzpicture} \draw [thin,green,fill=yellow] (0,.25) -- (.75,.25) -- (.75,.5) -- (0,.5); \end{tikzpicture} \vskip -.38cm \hskip -.38cm {{\textcolor{brown}{{\Large{\textbf{{HCO$_{3}$}}}}}}} } \end{minipage} }

Comment: @Hany Please stop repeating the same comment, and see [my earlier response](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283118/tikz-3-d-object/283127?noredirect=1#comment684858_283118) .